# ASP.NET MVC: How to pass data between incomplete forms (wizard)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, wizard

In my Asp.net MVC project, I have a scenerio where in,

1. User have a big form named **"Form A"** to fill up.
2. On filling half of the **Form A**,user is redirected to **Form B** to fill information.
3. On completing Form B, user is redirected back to Form A and at this time Form A should be pre-filled by the information user filled before going to Form B.

How and where to hold the half filled Form A information when user is filling Form B and how to refill Form A with this previously filled information?

Comment: While redirecting from form A->B, you need to save data in your database. Get and id and redirect to form B with that id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is this helpful [`Passing Data in an ASP.NET MVC Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

You can store values in ViewData or in Session to pass values while navigating from `Page A to Page B`

> For Big Data entry Pages - as suggested in comment- Best choice is to
>   store data into Database. as it will be quite annoying for user to
>   fill up data agian in any case.

Comment: If user accidentally closes the tab and lost session, then all data in previous form will be gone. I would still consider to keep "big data entry forms" in database rather than using session or viewdata.

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to `save the incomplete object/form` that you are building (you may consider forms A,B,C, etc... as parts of a **wizard**) to the database and just pass the `id to the next step` of the wizard. This also means you need to make some of the database fields nullable, but it has BIG advantage that you can also save the id in a cookie and allow the user to come back to the wizard at some later stage. This approach does not require any javascript or session state.

For a sample code samples on asp.net wizards you make look the following posts:

1) [Create a Wizard in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://afana.me/post/create-wizard-in-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx)

2) [Creating a simple form wizard in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://blog.degree.no/2012/03/creating-a-simple-form-wizard-in-asp-net-mvc-4/)

3) [Creating Wizard in ASP.NET MVC Part 2](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/652_Creating_Wizard_in_ASP_NET_MVC_Part_2.aspx)

Comment: Saving intermediate steps to a DB is the most robust approach(allowing use to come back and finish) but is more complex than the simple save is session/tempdata approach. You have to do a CBA (cost benefit analysis).